# Is it correct to say "My working hours were ad hoc."?

Tags: word-usage

If not, what is the right way to say it using the word *ad hoc*?

Comment: The Latin phrase **ad hoc** doesn't fit the context. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: "My working hours varied on a need-to basis."

Comment: That's perfectly clear, a much better way of expressing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Latin phrase “*ad hoc*” is not quite right for what you want to say and, in any case, is not understood by those who do not know Latin. If I said

> The policy of ‘oderint dum metuant’ is effective in the short run, but may not be in the long run

would you find the meaning obvious because this Latin is a complete sentence whereas “ad hoc” is a mere phrase.

Think about these:

> My working hours can vary with the changing requirements of the task.

> I have the flexibility to adjust my working hours to accommodate almost any situation.